# How to avoid calling copy constructor of the elements in a vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, constructor, stl

In the C++ example below:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct foo{
  foo(int i) : s( to_string(i) ){ cout << "init foo : "+s+"\n"; }
  foo(foo&& f) : s( move(f.s) ){ cout << "move foo : "+s+"\n"; }
  foo(const foo& f) : s(f.s){ cout << "copy foo : "+s+"\n"; }
  string s;
};

int main(){
  vector<foo> f;
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    cout << f.size() << endl;
    f.push_back( foo(i) );
  }
}
```

The output is :

```
0
init foo : 0
move foo : 0
1
init foo : 1
move foo : 1
copy foo : 0
2
init foo : 2
move foo : 2
copy foo : 0
copy foo : 1
3
init foo : 3
move foo : 3
4
init foo : 4
move foo : 4
copy foo : 0
copy foo : 1
copy foo : 2
copy foo : 3
```

It seems that `std::vector` will call the copy constructor for all `foo` elements in the container every time it changes its `capacity`.

Is there any way to force the use of move constructor instead of the copy constructor?

I do not know the final size of the `vector` so `vector::reserve` is not a possible choice.

Comment: declare the move-operator and constructor as noexcept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to state that your move constructor will not throw

```
foo(foo&& f) noexcept  : s(move(f.s)) { cout << "move foo : " + s + "\n"; }
```

Comment: Please lets close as a dupe instead of answering.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry, I knew the answer and didn't even bother searching.